# Artificial Intelligence Typing assistant for the desktop

Tags: artificial-intelligence

For mobile devices there exist many sophisticated applications for typing, such as swiftkey, Gboard, swype ...etc.

However I've not found any word prediction or typing assistant tools for the desktop. I've only found text replacements or other such software (Autohotkey) ...etc.

Is there any good easy to use AI based software that learns as you type? based on the application you type in?

Comment: For what OS? And what is your price limit, if it comes to paid solutions? I further assume it should just integrate "on system level", so it can be used in any application with typing input?

Answer (score 1):

I've found [TypingAid](https://github.com/ManiacDC/TypingAid) which describes itself as

```
TypingAid is a simple, compact, and handy auto-completion utility.    
It is customizable enough to be useful for regular typing and for programming.
```

It just seems like autocomplete for english rather than anything sophisticated though. There's certainly a lack of desktop level AI developments right now.